# How to perform cumulative sum inside iterrows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'b' : [1, 1, 1]})
df2

    b
0   1
1   1
2   1
```

I want to create a column 'cumsum' with the cumulative sum of column b starting row 2. Also I want to use iterrows to perform this. I tried below code but it doesnot seem to work.

```
for row_index, row in df2.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    df2.loc[row_index, 'cumsum'] = df2.loc[row_index, 'b'].cumsum()
```

My expected output:

```
    b   cum_sum
0   1   NaN
1   1   2
2   1   3
```

Comment: why not `df['b'].cumsum()`?

Comment: I want to use iterrows

Comment: You can add enumerate and do something like: ```df.iloc[i-1, "cumsum"]+df2.loc[row_index, 'b']```. Why iterrows though ?

Comment: Why do you need iterrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement, you may try this

```
for row_index, row in df2.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    df2.loc[row_index, 'cumsum'] = df2.loc[:row_index, 'b'].sum()

Out[10]:
   b  cumsum
0  1     NaN
1  1     2.0
2  1     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick to `iterrows()`:

```py
i=0
df2['cumsum']=0
col=list(df2.columns).index('cumsum')
for row_index, row in df2.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    df2.loc[row_index, 'cumsum'] = df2.loc[row_index, 'b']+df2.iloc[i, col]
    i+=1
```

Outputs:

```py
   b  cumsum
0  1       0
1  1       1
2  1       2
```